# GeoDjango: Distance Object is not serializable

Tags: django, serialization, geodjango, django-annotate

I am just learning the geo-django. I can find out the distance of all places from a point. But when I use `.values` method to the annotated `distance` field, I am getting

`TypeError: Object of type 'Distance' is not JSON serializable`

Here is my code snippets

```
#models.py
import uuid
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
class PlaceManager(models.GeoManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PlaceManager, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(
        latitude=models.ExpressionWrapper(models.Func('position', function='ST_X'), output_field=models.FloatField()),
        longitude=models.ExpressionWrapper(models.Func('position', function='ST_Y'), output_field=models.FloatField()),
    )
    return qs.distinct()

    def nearby_places(self, lat, lng):
        p = Point(lat, lng, srid=4326)
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(
            distance=Distance('position', p)
        )
        return qs.order_by('distance').distinct()


class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    position = models.PointField()
    address = models.TextField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = PlaceManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{},{}'.format(self.position.x, self.position.y)
```

Now the code snippets I have is like this

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class NearbyPlaces(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        p = Place.objects.nearby_places(30.45, -90.43)
        p = p.values('distance', 'address', 'latitude', 'longitude')
        return Response(p, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The value of `p` here is like this

```
<GeoQuerySet [{'distance': Distance(m=7596021.71574835), 'address': 'New York City, New York','latitude': 13.4586, 'longitude': 45.6789}]>
```

So all I needed here is `'distance': 7596021.71574835` instead of `'distance': Distance(m=7596021.71574835)`

Any help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest not using .values(), but instead use a serialiser. This way, when the serialiser gets the queryset, you can pick out the distance value and set it as the value.         http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class

Comment: Well found another way to do it. Just made an renderer and used it as default renderer class in `django rest framework.`

Comment: In your **#models.py**, just change **distance=Distance('position', p)** to **distance=Distance('position', p).m** and that will work. This way, you can keep all of the other code as it was **originally**, without the need for your Renderer class.

Comment: @ErionV here the value `p` may be dynamic.

Answer (score 8):

there is a more simple way, only need to change content in serializer.py:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_distance(self, obj):

        return obj.distance.m

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('distance')
```

Comment: This is much better solution, the first solution is an overkill all the way

Answer (score 3):

Just Found a way to do it.
Had to make a Renderer class in rest framework and handled the `Distance` objects in there. Code snippets are like this.

encoders.py

```
from rest_framework.utils.encoders import JSONEncoder
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance


class CustomJsonEncoderWithDistance(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Distance):
            print(obj)
            return obj.m
        return super(CustomJsonEncoderWithDistance, self).default(obj)
```

renders.py

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from .encoders import CustomJsonEncoderWithDistance


class CustomJsonRenderer(JSONRenderer):
     encoder_class = CustomJsonEncoderWithDistance
```

settings.py

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'app.renderers.CustomJsonRenderer',
    )
}
```